# Odin installation stuck at 70%

Tags: system-installation, release-odin

I'm trying to install elementary OS 6 Odin, beta 2, next to Windows 10. I selected *Custom installation* in Czech, chose the EFI partition for `/boot/efi`, an empty ext4 partition for `/` and a swap partition for swap. The installation starts, but it **gets stuck at 70 %**. The last output in the terminal is:

```
INFO: The following packages will be removed:
INFO:   btrfs-progs* casper* cifs-utils* discover* discover-data* distinst* dmraid*
```

(the list of packages continues on)

```
INFO: 0 updated, 0 installed, 42 to remove and 0 updated
INFO: After this operation, 42 MB will be freed on the disk.
```

I've tried to install the system many times, I even tried waiting for almost an hour, but to no avail. All of the partitions were freshly formatted with gparted.

**EDIT**: Also tested with the latest Release Candidate (`elementaryos-6.0-stable.20210805-rc.iso`), the problem remains.

**EDIT**: Also tested with the stable elementary 6

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering why my laptop is stuck at 70% for a good couple of hours. Looks like this bug made it to the final release. Changing language to English indeed fixes the issue.

Comment: you are the first Czech user of Elementary OS that I met in the discussions. Is it then possible to change the language and keyboard after installing the system? - - - - - Original Message: > Ahoj,
>
> jsi první český uživatel Elementary OS co jsem potkal v diskuzích.
Jde potom po instalaci systému změnit jazyk a klávesnice?

Comment: Ano, určitě jde! Dokonce se, tuším, elementary samo zeptá při prvním spuštění.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried doing the installation in English (US) and <s>not adding swap</s>. It fixed the issue.

**EDIT**: The problem is the language, not the swap. I tried installing again in US English but *with* a swap partition and it worked fine. Instalation in Czech failed.

I've [reported this](https://github.com/elementary/installer/issues/591) as a bug in the elementary installer.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it too and if I selected Czech language and US keyboard, i stalation aborted at the begining. If I selected US language and czech keyboard it has stucked at 70 percent. In complete english it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

and I confirm that I had the same problem with the installation in Czech, but if I install the system in English *then* change the system to Czech, everything works correctly.

Thanks to "m94a" for the advice here :-)

---

Original Message:

> Ahoj všem, a potvrzuji že jsem měl ten samý problém s instalací v CZ, ale při instalaci v ENG všechno proběhlo korektně, a při prvním spuštění systému jsem zvolil nastavení do CZ a všechno funguje. Díky "m94a" za rady zde :-)
>
> izi