# Why does elementary OS installation hang at 35%?

Tags: install

I am trying to install Elementary OS, the image is correct, but every time the installation freezes at 35 percent.
[image]

Comment: I have also run into issues when trying to install Elementary using a language that uses characters that are not the standard A~Z. What I have had to do is install the OS first in English, then change the language. This is suboptimal, but it gets around the initial installation problem ...

Comment: I think that trying to install it in English will be able to show if it is a bug in the new installer.

Comment: It may be working in the background. Leave it for an hour and check again please.

Comment: Related: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/28242/19079 https://github.com/elementary/installer/issues/591

Answer (score 0):

Related to Russian language selection.
Had same issue today with elementaryos-6.1-stable.20211218-rc. After reading this [Odin installation stuck at 70%](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28242/odin-installation-stuck-at-70) I installed english version first and then switched to Russian UI using the Language settings panel and works like a charm